# R histogram with unequal breaks and same width

Tags: r, statistics, histogram

I currently have a histogram (see image) where I have given the argument breaks a set of values with unequal spacing between (see example code below). This results in the bin widths being uneven and I just wondered if there was a way to make it so the bin widths are equal, whilst keeping the breaks as they are, by adapting the existing code. This would just be to make it look better visually. Ideally I would like to keep using the hist() function as well.

```
set.seed(10)

results<-rnorm(200, 2, 0.65)

new_breaks<-c(0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5)

hist(results, main="Histogram", xlab="Results", breaks=new_breaks, cex=1.5)
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: Are you really trying to make a histogram at this point? Histograms are versy specifically a kernel density estimate for continuous random variables such that the area under all the bars sums to 1. Sounds like you really just want a bar chart of frequencies. Maybe something like `barplot(table(cut(results, new_breaks)))`. Otherwise I don't really understand how you would want the x-axis labeled

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick. That seems to work, the only problem is that the x-axis labels are now like this: (0.4,0.5] (0.8,1.2] (2.4,2.8] (3.2,3.3]. Is there a way to display values as in the histogram I created?